# Unable to list default active directory in Azure cloud

Tags: azure, active-directory

The service admin of Azure account has added me as a co-admin, and also has assigned me the role of Global Admin, but I am unable to see Default Directory in Active Directory section. Do I need to have any other permission apart from the above mentioned ?

Comment: Are you using a live id or an organization id?

Comment: Also, are you added as a `Guest` or a `Member` user type in the Azure AD? In my experience even if you're made a `Global Admin` but if your user type is `Guest`, you may not have permissions to do certain things.

Answer (score 0):

By default only global administrator will have access to the default azure active directory in a given subscription. Or You will have to be user administrator in order to create and manage users in the default active directory. But they cannot create a new administrator though.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-assign-admin-roles/

Comment: Hi,
Service administrator has already assigned be Global Administrator role, but still can list/access the default directory.

Comment: global admin has the privileges. may be try signing out and log in .

Comment: Had a chat with Azure support, the thing was that my client had registered with Non-Microsoft account and assigned me the subscription, which was causing the whole issue.

Comment: Oh ok. But still a user given a role should work. ID shouldn't matter.